# Creating a list with multiple units of measurements of floats in F#

Tags: list, f#, units-of-measurement

So, I've tried to get around this in various ways, but I just can't make this work.

Is there any way to make a list that contains values of varying units of measurement (all based on floats)? For example:

```
let myList = [0.07<ms>; 0.9; 7.2<mm>;]
```

As they are treated as different types, you cannot put them in the same list. I tried declaring the list as `let myList : float<_> list = ...`, and giving dimensionless numbers a unit of measurement, but I still got a typing error: expecting float<'u> but got float.

I am unable to use a tuple/n-ple as I do not know the number of values that will be in the list.

I am quite new to F# and have spent quite a while scouring the documents and web on storage, but haven't found a solution. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give the motivation of doing so? The compiler is forcing you to do a good thing.

Comment: I want to use the list as a parameter to a function, where the values will be used slightly differently, depending on which object (created from a derived class, all are from the same abstract class) is being computed with.
Why is it forcing me to do a good thing? I don't understand!

Comment: UoM is actually invented for very this reason: preventing you from accidental mixture of `seconds` and `meters`. The functions supposed to process the values will also infer proper argument types. Please share some usage code so we figured out how you are planning to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll need to give a longer example that shows how you want to use this list. Otherwise it is difficult to give a good answer, because it depends on the use.

If you just want to create a list of numbers that represent different things, then you can consider using a discriminated union to differentiate between them:

```
type Numeric =
  | Length of float<mm>
  | Time of float<ms>
  | Unitless of float

let myList = [ Time 0.07<ms>; Unitless 0.9; Length 7.2<mm>;]
```

Then you can create a list that contains different numbers (with different physical meanings). When iterating over the list, you'll need to use pattern matching to extract the value.

Alternatively, you can just drop all units when creating the list, but then you lose the guarantees provided by units of measure (meaning that when you get some value from the list, you won't know what unit it had and you could interpret it wrongly):

```
let myList = [ float 0.07<ms>; 0.9; float 7.2<mm>;]
```

You could also use [an F# library that lets you track units at runtime](http://trelford.com/blog/post/Runtime-Units-of-Measure-for-F.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful! 
I can't believe I didn't think of trying discriminated unions, this seems to work well for what I want to do... as far as I can tell at the moment! 
I'm still in the sort of investigating stage so I didn't have much code to show and what I do have doesn't make much sense at this stage, I apologise and thank you for trying to help anyway. :)

Thank you for the link also, I was vaguely reading about some things relating to this and I hadn't come across that post yet.

Answer (score 1):

All members of a list [must have the same type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx).  A `float<ms>` is not the same as a `float<mm>`.