# F# unordered collection type to represent resources and costs

Tags: collections, types, f#, units-of-measurement

To practise a little F#, I'm building myself a simple game. The game involves `resources` that players can spend. There are 3 kinds of resources. Items and actions in the game have an associated `cost` that can combine amounts of any number of these resources (or none, for free actions). I started implementing this much along the lines of : [Creating a list with multiple units of measurements of floats in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567081/creating-a-list-with-multiple-units-of-measurements-of-floats-in-f)

```ml
[<Measure>] type gold
[<Measure>] type wood
[<Measure>] type stone

type Resource =
    | Gold of int<gold> 
    | Wood of int<wood>
    | Stone of int<stone>
```

Now I need a collection data type to represent a `cost`. I want it to :

- Contain `Resources`. Ideally it would be constrained to no more than 1 Resource of each type, but that safety I could do without.
- Be unordered. `(1<gold>, 2<wood>)` needs to equal `(2<wood>, 1<gold>)` ideally without redefining equality for the type.
- Be easily summable with another collection of the same type (actions may have optional costs which will add up to the normal cost) and subtractable (from a player's pool of resources).

What would be a good F# collection type to do that ? I realized not many are unordered. I was looking at `Set<'T>` but the "based on binary trees" part has me a little confused and I'm not sure it suits my needs.

What do you think ? Did I miss something obvious in my design ?

Comment: Internally a set is a binary tree, so the elements in it are ordered (by comparison), but the order in which they were added to the set is not important

Comment: I see. `Resources` aren't always comparable so I guess Set is not a good fit here. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to represent resources containing some amount of gold, wood and stone, then it might make more sense to use a record type rather than a collection (e.g. a map or list) of discriminated unions.

For example, if you define your record like this:

```
type Resources =
  { Gold : int<gold> 
    Wood : int<wood>
    Stone : int<stone> }
```

Then a value of `Resources` satisfies all your criteria - it contains at most one filed for each kind of resource (it contains exactly one field of each kind, but the value can be zero). The fields are ordered, but the order does not matter (when creating the value) and you can also easily define `+` operator on the type:

```
type Resources =
  { Gold : int<gold> 
    Wood : int<wood>
    Stone : int<stone> }
  static member (+) (r1:Resources, r2:Resources) =
    { Gold = r1.Gold + r2.Gold
      Wood = r1.Wood + r2.Wood
      Stone = r1.Stone + r2.Stone }
  static member Zero = 
    { Gold = 0<gold>; Stone = 0<stone>; Wood = 0<wood> }
```

I also added `Zero` member, which makes it easier to create the record if you only want to set one of the resources. For example:

```
let r1 = { Resources.Zero with Gold = 2<gold> }
let r2 = { Resources.Zero with Wood = 4<wood> }
r1 + r2
```

Comment: I had actually thought of something like this but set the idea aside as too simple/rigid with too much code duplication, hoping there would be a more efficient way. Turns out it's really quite elegant and does all I need ! Thanks Tomas.

Comment: @guillaume31 If you had lots of different kinds of resources, then this would be a bit limited - and I would perhaps use something like `Map`, but I don't think that would be the case in a simple game...

Comment: Adding a `Zero` member doesn't just make it easier to create a record, it also helps with library functions which expect a type with `Zero` member, eg. `Seq.sum[r1; r2]`

Comment: Tomas's answer takes the form of a monoid, which is a very useful pattern for this kind of situation.  I can highly recommend this series to learn more (using F# examples):  http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/understanding-monoids.html